# Are fan questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I was about to ask what is it called, colloquially, the organ that is used to play baseball tunes live in the stadium, and whether there is a common brand or model that they prefer to use for that, but I don't know if these kind of questions are on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, definitely. Quoting from [our site scope](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Sports Stack Exchange is for [...] fans of all sports and forms of competitive physical activity.